# R: Forest plot difference of means from lsmean?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I want to recreate a plot that looks like this?

[image]

Here is an example, the closest I can get is a ggplot that looks like this.

```
typing = data.frame(
 type = rep(c("A","B","C"), each=4),
 hours = c(60,72,61,50, 54,68,66,59, 56,56,55,51),
 pain = c(85,95,69,58, 41,74,71,52, 41,34,50,40))

typing.lm = lm(pain ~ hours + type, data = typing)
typing.lsm = lsmeans(typing.lm, pairwise ~ type )


plot(typing.lsm[[2]] ) + xlab("mean difference") + ylab("comparisons")
```

the resulting plot looks like this.

[image]

is there a forest plot equivalent to this, preferably in ggplot? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a two step solution. First you'll need to transform the data to get some variables that will make it easier to construct the desired plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

# Create the df used to make the plot
df <- typing.lsm$contrasts %>%
  # Transform data to tibble
  as_tibble() %>%
  # Add labs for y axis and define linetype according to p.value
  mutate(labs_y = paste0(contrast, ", p=", round(p.value, 2)),
         line_typ = ifelse(p.value <= 0.05, "dashed", "solid")) %>%
  # Change labs for y axis from "-" to "vs"
  mutate_at(vars(labs_y), function(x) gsub(" - ", " vs ", x))

# Minimum value in the x axis to set the plot limits, as well as the left axis line
# see second geom_vline. This can probably be calculated from the data.
min_val <- -5

# plot
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = estimate,
         y = contrast)) +
  # Add point for estimate
  geom_point()+
  # Add error bars, use line_typ to set line type
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmax = estimate + SE,
                    xmin = estimate - SE,
                    lty = line_typ),
                show.legend = F,
                width = 0.3) +
  # Add estimates values as text
  geom_text(aes(label = round(estimate, 2)), 
            # nudge position in x and y directions
            nudge_x = 2,
            nudge_y = 0.1) +
  # Add dashed vertical line in 0 Difference (y-axis)
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, lty = "dashed") +
  # Make line for second axis (left side)
  geom_vline(xintercept = min_val )  +
  # Put x axis in the right side and make second axis in bottom
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = ""),
                     limits = c(min_val,32),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  # Change y axis position and add labs
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right",
                   labels = df$labs_y) +
  # Change axis titles
  labs(x = "Difference", y = "") +
  # Add cowplot theme
  theme_cowplot()+
  # Final theme adjustments
  # Remove ticks and text from bottom secondary axis
  theme(axis.ticks.x.bottom = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: This is incredible thank you. It works great.  Also as you mentioned I was able to programmically determine the the min  and max, although the calculating the the label position was a bit more difficult, but this works! many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions here (not specific to your data) -- https://www.middleprofessor.com/files/applied-biostatistics_bookdown/_book/plotting-models.html#how-to-generate-an-effects-plot